# Python pick item from list of classes

Tags: python, list, function, class, object

So first I'm trying to make a class, which holds an item's name, price, and quantity available.  Then I wanted to make a function that will deduct the quantity sold to a buyer after they enter the amount they are buying, and then calculate the total price.

Now to add on top of that, I am trying to have the user select from a list of items.
The problem is it seem I seem to be getting errors around the time the program starts running the 'buy' function.

```
class Retail:
def __init__(self, price, unitsOnHand, description):
    self.price = price
    self.unitsOnHand = unitsOnHand
    self.description = description
def buy (self):
    print ("How many are you buying?")
    quant = int(input("Amount:  "))
    unitsOnHand -= quant
    subto = price * quant
    total = subto * 1.08
    print ("There are now ", unitsOnHand, " left")
    print ("The total price is $", total)

box = Retail(4.95, 20, "Boxes")
    paper =Retail(1.99, 50, "Big Stacks of Paper")
staples =Retail(1.00, 200, "Staples")
ilist = (box, paper, staples)
print ("Which are you buying? ", [box.description, paper.description,    staples.description])
ioi = input("Please use the exact word name: ")
if ioi == 'box':
    Retail.buy(ilist[0])
elif ioi == 'paper':
    Retail.buy(ilist[1])
elif ioi == 'staples':
    Retail.buy(ilist[2])
```

The error I get when I tried to run it is

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XXXXXX/XXXX/Code/Retailclass", line 22, in <module>
Retail.buy(ilist[0])
  File "C:/Users/XXXXXX/XXXX/Code/Retailclass", line 9, in buy
unitsOnHand -= quant
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'unitsOnHand' referenced before assignment
```

I'm guessing is that it doesn't see the values I already assigned to the item, and if that is the case, how do I get it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have pointed out your error, but the other thing that is wrong is your `buy` call needs to be done on an instance of the object, not the class itself. In other words, right now you are executing buy on the Retail *class* where you need to execute it on instance (objects) of the class.

I have another suggestion to help organize your code. Use a dictionary to map the keys to the various objects to make your loop a bit cleaner.  Putting all that together (and some other checks), here is an updated version of your class:

```
class Retail(object):

    def __init__(self, price, unitsOnHand, description):
        self.price = price
        self.unitsOnHand = unitsOnHand
        self.description = description

    def buy(self):
        if self.unitsOnHand == 0:
            print('Sorry, we are all out of {} right now.'.format(self.description))
            return
        print("How many are you buying? We have {}".format(self.unitsOnHand))
        quant = int(input("Amount:  "))
        while quant > self.unitsOnHand:
            print('Sorry, we only have {} left'.format(self.unitsOnHand))
            quant = int(input("Amount:  "))
        self.unitsOnHand -= quant
        subto = self.price * quant
        total = subto * 1.08
        print("There are now {} left".format(self.unitsOnHand))
        print("The total price is ${}".format(total))
        return

stock = {}
stock['box'] = Retail(4.95, 20, "Boxes")
stock['paper'] = Retail(1.99, 50, "Big Stacks of Paper")
stock['staples'] = Retail(1.00, 200, "Staples")

print("Which are you buying? {}".format(','.join(stock.keys())))
ioi = input("Please use the exact word name: ")

while ioi not in stock:
   print("Sorry, we do not have any {} right now.".format(ioi))
   print("Which are you buying? {}".format(','.join(stock.keys())))
   ioi = input("Please use the exact word name: ")

stock[ioi].buy()
```

Comment: Thanks.  I also realized I should apply self.price within 'buy' as well.